# Ubuntu freezes when connection is lost to remote share mounted locally

Tags: networking, mount, samba

If I mount a remote share (CIFS) locally, and then lose connection to that remote server, I find I am unable to unmount the folder, and sometimes, even worse, the local system hangs and the only solution I have for this is a reboot.

Since I manage servers with many services, rebooting so often is very impractical. Is there any solution for this problem besides reboot?

Comment: It is a long standing problem with samba and NFS. Servers windows or linux ? See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1321354 and https://serverfault.com/questions/622238/linux-cifs-samba-mount-hangs-for-several-minutes

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/450206/how-to-fix-a-software-caused-connection-abort-error-in-ubuntu-14-04